# Cannot remove node "0" because no matching node was found in the Store

Tags: react-native, node-modules

**I am trying to run an app. It is successfully running but shows the below error.**

Uncaught Error: Cannot remove node "0" because no matching node was found in the Store.
at /Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:48
at f.emit (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:48)
at /Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:48
at /Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:48
at Array.forEach ()
at A.e.onmessage (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:48)
at A.t (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:39)
at A.emit (events.js:315)
at e.exports.L (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:3)
at e.exports.emit (events.js:315)
at e.exports.dataMessage (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:3)
at e.exports.getData (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:3)
at e.exports.startLoop (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:3)
at e.exports._write (/Applications/React Native Debugger.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/node_modules/react-devtools-core/dist/standalone.js:3)
at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387)

**Can anyone help in this?**

react native ---> **0.63.3**
react ---> **16.13.1**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `react-devtools-core` (or react-native) are you using? This could be because your React DevTools backend and your React DevTools UI versions are misaligned.